# b%a where b is very large

Tags: c++, modulus, largenumber

We are given two integers `a` and `b`, `a <= 100000`, `b < 10^250`. I want to calculate b%a. I found this algorithm but can't figure out how it works.

```
int mod(int a, char b[])
{
    int r = 0;
    int i;
    for(i=0;b[i];++i)
    {
      r=10*r +(b[i] - 48);
      r = r % a;
    }
    return r;
}
```

Please explain the logic behind this. I know basic properties of modular mathematics.

Thanks.

Comment: The only magic number here is 48. It is ASCII code of symbol "0". So `"0" - 48 == 0;` and `"1" - 48 == 1;` and so on. The rest of the code is up to you to understand.

Comment: @MarkGraph your sarcasm is better than your guess.

Comment: The piece of code you "found" does not take "two integers, a and b", so this is not a very good start.

Comment: @teivaz i knew what 48 did. That was not magic at all. i was looking for was how that algorithm got the answer for b%a.

Comment: @DanielDaranas i wrote that we are given two integers. I did not say anything about how I input it. In this case, as is obvious the bigger number b is input as string.

Comment: Integer will **always** be smaller than 10^250

Comment: He didn't deserve the downvotes. He forgot to explain how the value iof `b` is entered and supposed you downvoters will understand it. This is the only thing he got wrong about. His question about how this function computes the modulo **is** interesting and easily linked to the way one effciently compute a polynomial. [Horner's Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horner's_method)

Answer (score 3):

It's pretty easy to figure out if you know modular arithmetics, expression `(b[n] + 10 * b[n - 1] + ... + 10^k * b[k] + ... + 10^n * b[0]) modulo a` which is technically initial problem statement could be simplified to `(...((b[0] modulo a) * 10 + b[1]) modulo a) * 10 + ... + b[n]) modulo a` which is what your algorithm does.

To prove that their equal we may calculate coefficient modulo `a` before `b[i]` in the second expression, it's easy to see that for `b[i]` there will be exactly `n - i` times we'll have to multiply it by 10 (the last one which is `n` will be multiplied 0 times, the one before him 1 time and so on ...). So modulo `a` it equals `10 ^ (n - i)` which is the same coefficient before `b[i]` in the first expression.

Thus since all coefficients before `b[i]` in both expressions would be equal, it's obvious that both expressions are equal to `(k_0 * b[0] + k_1 * b[1] ... + k_n * b[n])` modulo `a` and thus they are equal modulo `a`.

`48` is char code for `0` digit, so `(b[i] - 48)` is conversion from char to digit.

Comment: I don't get how it has been simplified to (...((b[0] modulo a) * 10 + b[1]) modulo a) * 10 + ... + b[n]) modulo a

Comment: @AbhilashSingh to calculate coefficient before `b[i]` you will have to multiple `10 modulo a` from exactly `n - i` parenthesis which is the same as `(10^(n - i)) modulo a` from the first expression.

Answer (score 1):

Basically this function implements [Horner's Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horner's_method) to compute the decimal value of `b`.

As @Predelnik explained, the value of `b` is a polynomial whose coefficients are the digits of `b` and the variable `x` is `10`. The function computes the modulo on every iteration using the fact that modulo is compatible with addition and multiplication:

```
(a+b) % c = ((a%c) + (b%c)) % c
(a*b) % c = ((a%c) * (b%c)) % c
```